# How to print complex numbers in C++

Tags: c++

I am playing around with classes in C++. Currently I am working on a class for complex numbers and want to be able to print them in the following format: `-2+3i`, `1-4i`. That means, that I want the real part to have only a sign if it is negative. In contrast the imaginary part should have always a sign whether it is positive or negative.

I tried the following which did not work as expected:

```
inline void Complex::print() const {
    std::cout << x;
    std::cout << std::showpos << y << "i" << std::endl;
}
```

This method prints also for the real part the sign if it is positive. Why does `std::showpos` affect the first line?

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Use a couple of if-statements. `if (real < 0)` etc. Sidenote: Instead of calling the components `x` and `y`, it would make more sense to refer to them as `real` and `imaginary`, especially since that's what you do when you're speaking

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this as an exercise or due to lack of required features, if not is worth noting that [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) exists.

Comment: BTW, there already is a [standard library for complex numbers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/complex).

Comment: I would suggest to change the title. THe question seems to be about printing the sign rather than complex numbers. If it was the latter using `std::complex` would be the way to go, and the current title for sure will attract users seeking for how to print `std::complex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the showpos format flag is set, a plus sign (+) precedes every non-negative numerical value inserted into the stream (including zeros). This flag can be unset with the noshowpos manipulator.

Minor change in your code:

```
inline void Complex::print() const {
    std::cout << std::noshowpos << x;
    std::cout << std::showpos << y << "i" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`showpos` is "sticky", and applies to every following number until it's changed back with `noshowpos`.

You can use `showpos` with a local stream to avoid messing with `std::cout`:

```
inline void Complex::print() const {
    std::ostringstream y_stream;
    y_stream << showpos << y;
    std::cout << x 
              << y_stream.str() << 'i'
              << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: But this approach prints, for example, `1--2i` if the imaginary part is negative, right?

Comment: @Samuel Yes, I was too quick and though too little.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `std::showpos` flag affects every number inserted into the stream. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/showpos/)

Have you tried using `if` statements?

```
if (x > 0)
{
    std::cout << "+";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never use `std::noshowpos`, `std::cout` will keep the `showpos` flag, so that next time you call `print()` it affects `x` (and any other number you ever print with `std::cout` in your program).

So either use `std::noshowpos` directly after printing `y`:

```
std::cout << std::showpos << y << std::noshowpos << "i" << std::endl;
```

or directly before printing `x`:

```
std::cout << std::noshowpos << x;
```